# How can I find $\mathbf{J}$ from the equation for $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{J}$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

How can I find $\mathbf{J}$ from the following equation
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}= ∇\left(∇^2 (∇ψ^†⋅\mathbf{A})+∇⋅(\mathbf{A} ∇^2 ψ^† )\right)⋅∇ψ+∇ψ^†⋅∇\left(∇^2 (∇ψ⋅\mathbf{A} )+∇⋅(\mathbf{A} ∇^2 ψ)\right)+\left[∇^2(∇^2 ψ^† )∇ψ+∇ψ^† ∇^2 (∇^2 ψ)-∇^2 ψ^† ∇(∇^2 ψ)-∇(∇^2 ψ^† ) ∇^2 ψ\right]⋅\mathbf{A}
$$
$\psi\equiv\psi(\mathbf r)$ and $\psi^†\equiv\psi^†(\mathbf r)$ are scalar field operators. And $\mathbf{A}\equiv\mathbf{A}(\mathbf r)$ is a vector field.

Comment: Without further conditions there’s not much you can say. If $J$ satisfies the equation then so does $J + \operatorname{curl} B$ where $B$ is arbitrary.